Can I use Resolume Arena video output as texutre / video input in blender?
Is it possible to use resolume arena output as video input/ texture using in blender?
I was wondering if I can use resolume arena to do some mock up in some stage design animations using blender?
Vinco

You'll have to explain what "resolume arena" is and what format it exports!

No. Blender is not suited for Realtime applications and doesnt support pipes like ndi, etc. I recommend Touchdesigner which can support fbx well.

Many thanks.....I was researching to do it the other way round. I found that using texture sharing through Spout can stream the render to Resolume Arena. This is what i am researching : https://vjun.io/jacobmesick/blender-in-resolume-through-a-spout-plugin-a90

You'll have to explain what "resolume arena" is and what format it exports! –
< Resolume arena is a playback and VJ software. I wanna use them to provide the video content to blender in real-time. This the arena : https://www.resolume.com/
